# Install Visual Studio 2015 on Linux Mint using Wine

Tags: linux, visual-studio, linux-mint, wine

I am using Linux Mint and I have the Visual Studio 2015 exe installation file.

I use Wine for Windows applications, but it doesn't work with VS.

Has someone successfully installed VS using Wine on Linux Mint?

Answer (score 0):

VS 2015 doesn't works with wine, because VS will require a full Windows stack. Use virtualization for example VirtualBox or VMware.